# VB.NET - Duplicate existing form in FOR loop

Tags: vb.net, forms, for-loop

Hey, I'm building a code editor app in VB.NET (Framework 4.0) and it opens all ".por" files into individual forms consisting of a MenuBar and TextBox (multi-line).
Currently I have 20 forms (all duplicates of the first on I designed) and if there are say 4 ".por" files in a directory, the first four will open up while the others hide.

I think it would be far more efficient by coding a new form For each item in form1's ListView...but I want the next so many to be a copy of the first form I designed since I spent a good bit on it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, what`s your question???

Comment: My question is, how do I make a copy of an existing form for a certain amount of files? Using 20 forms which are all the same then limiting the end user to only being able to load 20 .por files is inconvenient and inefficient. I want to take it down to just the one form which is copied for each .por file in a directory.
Screenshot: http://www.mediafire.com/imageview.php?quickkey=mzohbemzzmd&thumb=5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use tabs instead.

It wasn't difficult, the problem was I didn't know how to use a form I couldn't see.

By sticking to tabs and making a huge IF statement, simply making a new tab for each new file, and I'm getting used to using controls which haven't actually been created with the designer.

Just passing through a wall here...